# How to pass data from Android app to Samsung Bixby capsule?

Tags: android, samsung-mobile, bixby

I want to add Bixby voice command to my Android app. My app has 2 activities. Activity_1 calls a service and passes the data to Activity_2. Activity_2 has several buttons and does some actions with the data.

I don't know how to use Bixby voice commands to call those actions (equivalent to pressing the buttons)

Is it possible to pass data from Activity_1 to a Bixby capsule (and replace Activity_2 entirely with the Bixby capsule)?

Or is it possible to call from a Bixby capsule a method from Activity_2?

Any help will be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Bixby currently does not support this functionality. I would recommend that you raise a Feature Request in [our community forum](https://support.bixbydevelopers.com/hc/en-us/community/topics/360000183273-Feature-Requests). This forum is open to other Bixby developers who can upvote it, leading to more visibility within the community and with the Product Management team.

Answer (score 0):

You can have bixby call the same webservice your android app is calling from inside the Bixby JavaScript code. That's probably the best way.

https://bixbydevelopers.com/dev/docs/sample-capsules/samples/http